# How to replace a number sequence using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I try to replace "_v(anydigit)" to "_index" :

example :

`file_v01.jpg to file_index.jpg` using `re.sub("_v\d\d","_index",file)`

or

`file_v0001.jpg to file_index.jpg` using  `re.sub("_v\d\d\d\d","_index",file)`

Those scripts works fine. But what if i don't know the digits . The number of digits is random , so it maybe _v1 or _v001 or _v023445. It should find all the digits behind the '_v' until it reach a non digit.

How can i catch it ?

Comment: `\d+` matches 1+ digits. Study [Lesson 7: Mr. Kleene, Mr. Kleene](https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators) to get familiarized with the basic quantifier(s).